# Required field runtime jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, requiredfieldvalidator

this is my function

```
function ProvinceChanged() {
    if ($('#ProvinceId').val() == 'New') 
    {
        $('#NewProvince').css('display', 'block');
        $('#CityId').html('<option>New</option>');
        CityChanged();
    }
```

how to make this "NewProvince" required? and with the fields "please enter" should when it is left empty before form submit

Comment: You can try jQuery Validation Plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @Pavan where to use this validate function? below this line?

     $('#NewProvince').css('display', 'block');